# How to derive if the reaction is endothermic or exothermic based on rate constants at different temperatures?

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, energy

> Listed in the table are forward and reverse rate constants for the reaction $$\ce{2NO (g)  <=> N_2 (g) + O_2 (g)}$$
>   \begin{array}{ccc}
> \text{Temperature}/\pu{K} & k_f/\pu{M^-1s^-1} & k_r /\pu{M^-1s^-1} \\\hline
> 1400 & 0.29 & 1.1\times10^{-6}\\
> 1500 & 1.3  & 1.4\times10^{-5}\\
> \end{array}
>   Is the reaction endothermic or exothermic?

In my book the solution is given as

> $k_r$ increase more than $k_f$, this means that $E_a$ (reverse) is greater than $E_a$ (forward). The reaction is exothermic when $E_a$ (reverse) > $E_a$ (forward).

I can not understand what they mean by the given answer. 
Can anybody explain it in more detail?

Comment: My hint is use the van't Hoff equation.

Comment: @Zhe I am not understanding how to use that

Comment: The van't Hoff equation tells you what direction the equilibrium will shift as you change the temperature. It depends on whether the reaction is endothermic or exothermic. For endothermic reactions, as you increase temperature, the equilibrium shifts more towards products. The opposite is true for exothermic reactions.

Comment: So @Zhe can we write -$\Delta$H =E$_a$(forward) - E$_a$(reverse)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiJ0M.jpg

Comment: @orthocresol so the answer of this should be exothermic . Am I correct

Comment: @user123733 Seems fine, but computing $E_{a}$ is none trivial. Are you assuming the same prefactor? For what it's worth, there's no reason to calculate $E_{a}$. It's much easier to just look at the rate constants.